# Lifecycle activity stopwatch

Tags: android

I am new to android. 
Learning about the lifecycle of the activity.
I am having difficulty understanding the logic here.
There are three variables:
boolean `running`, `wasRunning`, and int `seconds`.
I am not able to understand  the code inside `onStop` and `onStart`. Can someone please explain the logic of the code shared below that why are we using `wasRunning`?

```
 public void runTimer()
        {
            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    running = true;
                }
            });

            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    running = false;
                }
            });

            reset.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    running = false;
                    seconds = 0;
                }
            });


     Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int hours = seconds / 3600;
                    int min = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
                    int sec = seconds % 60;
                    String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, min, sec);
                    text.setText(time);
                    if (running) {

                        seconds++;


                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            wasRunning=running;

            running=false;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if(wasRunning);
            running=true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very poor code.  It keeps a continually running timer, and uses a flag to ignore it when not running.  Instead, when the activity is stopped it should stop the timer to use fewer CPU resources.  But here's what it does:

OnStop-  when the activity is backgrounded, start ignoring timer events, and set a flag (wasRunning) to know whether it was running when it was last active.

onStart-  if the timer was running last time the app was foregrounded, stop ignoring timer events.

So the combo of these two functions will ignore all timer events when in the background, but start listening to them again when it regains the foreground.

Comment: its the code from head first android book. I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Books for beginners rarely have good code. They aim for simple. This will work, it's just not how you should actually do it